# Using SqlGeometry.MakeValid to get a counter-clockwise polygon in SQL Server

Tags: geojson, sql-server, spatial-database, geography, nettopologysuite

The data I've loaded from a shapefile into a geometry column in SQL Server (using NetTopologySuite) is not producing valid GeoJSON when I export it because it doesn't follow the right-hand rule.

I thought this would be easy to fix with the `MakeValid()` function, but it's not correcting the issue.

I tried with a simplified geometry as below:

```
declare @geom geometry
select @geom = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((
0 0,
0 1,
2 1,
2 0, 
0 0
))', 4326)

select @geom, @geom.IsValidDetailed()
```

SQL Server says it's valid (24400: Valid), so presumably that's why it's not fixing it in the `MakeValid` function.

What's the best way to resolve this? I've seen an option to use:
`UPDATE table SET geom = geom.STUnion(geom.STStartPoint())` which works for simple polygons, but I'm not sure how well it will work for more complex geometries.

Comment: Is using ogr2ogr an acceptable option for you?

Comment: @user30184 Not really. I believe that's a command line tool, where I need it embedded in a website so a user can upload a shapefile and it gets processed (preferably using C#).

Comment: How about GDAL generally if used through C# or Python bindings? But it does feel like a heavy tool if the only problem is with ring orientations.

Comment: Yeah - I'm so close with NetTopologySuite loading the data in, there's just this one small issue, which `MakeValid` is *supposed* to fix. So I'm wondering if there's something wrong with how I'm doing it, rather than looking for a new tool.

Answer (score 2):

I've started working with NetTopologySuite, and have the same problem. I found a [fix here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247429/fixing-orientation-in-net-topology-suite). Simply put:

```
if (!polygon.Shell.IsCCW) polygon = polygon.Reverse();
```

If you have Geometries you will need to cast, and if you have MultiPolygons you will have to iterate through each of them.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had thought I would fix this in Sql Server using a spatial function like `MakeValid`, but as that didn't work, I've found a way to fix it when loading the data from the shape file, using NetTopologySuite.

I was using:

```
var factory = new GeometryFactory();
using (var shapeFileDataReader = new ShapefileDataReader(filePath, factory))
```

But simply changing the factory worked, like this:

```
var factory = new OgcCompliantGeometryFactory();
using (var shapeFileDataReader = new ShapefileDataReader(filePath, factory))
```